# XSLT add root node if not exists

Tags: xslt

I have some XML and having a difficult time transforming it.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cars xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Car> ... </Car>
</Cars>
```

I would like to change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Depot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Cars>
    <Car> ... </Car>
  </Cars>
</Depot>
```

Sounds simple enough but the problem is some data is already in the expected format, in which case I don't want to apply the transform. How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Some starting XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Cars">
<Depot>
  <Cars>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </Cars>
</Depot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you share any XSLT you have currently tried? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only want to match `Cars` if it is the root element, so instead of your template matching "Cars", change it to match "/Cars"

```
<xsl:template match="/Cars">
```

Try this XSLT (which I have slightly amended to get the first template to call the identity template)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/Cars">
      <Depot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
      </Depot>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works great, tried with XML already having the depot tag and does the job thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is just necessary to use a choose in the root template to test if the node Depot exists, if not create it:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Depot">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Depot>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </Depot>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also gives same output.

```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

    <xsl:template match="Cars">
    <Depot>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </Depot>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```